# How do I load a folder of images on a visual c++ windows form application

Tags: winforms, visual-c++

I have a visual c++ windows form application (empty) made on visual studio 2008

I would like to add a button so users can browse a folder.

after they select the folder I would like to "scan" that folder and list all the images (JPG, PNG and GIF) in my windows form application.

can anyone provide me with the steps required ?

Thank you

Comment: Managed code (windows forms?) - really? Or did you mean MFC and chose the Windows Forms tag because it's a Windows app?

Comment: I have created a project from Visual C++ and I choose the Windows Forms Application template.

Comment: So you know you'll be writing managed code in C++/CLI with ^ all over the place, and that's ok with you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is any automatic way to scan image files but since you have only 3 extensions, you could try the following per extension,

```
string[] imageList = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg");
```

where path is the folder you browse to using the browse folder dialog (NOT the browse file dialog).

It returns a string of all the files in the directory along with their full paths. Optionally you can trim of the path using a simple .Split('\') command.

I'm not sure if the string[] will work in C++ as the syntax seems to want the hat symbol, as seen below.

```
array<String^>^imageList
```

Here is the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) for the getfiles method.